# w3C answer not work for loading XML in IE

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to load a XML file in IE 7/8 and I search the answer from the w3c. I found the answer, the following code, but when I use the javascript to do that, it shows 'Access is denied' error to my js file. Can anyone help me?

w3c link: [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_loadxml)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadXML(location) {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // for IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",location,false);        // error in here, even I type the link here, also not work
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: w3schools.com has absolutely nothing to do with the real W3, they're just trying to sell useless certifications. See http://w3fools.com/

Comment: This question's title is why I hate W3Schools.

Comment: what `location` you try to load and where's your code resides in? You probably encounter the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Also, this is an ajax call. If you want to use ajax, rather rely on a framework like jquery (www.jquery.com) for example. If you want to get your xml file, make sure that the path (location) is correct and visible on the web, and that you aren't trying to grab it from another domain. Else you will get a sandbox error.

Comment: are you opening this page locally or using a webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of IE does not support responseXML here is what you do:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
   var response = xhttp.responseText;

   var XMLdoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
   XMLdoc.loadXML(http_request.responseText);
}else {
   var XMLdoc = http_request.responseXML;
}
```

Comment: @lbu, thank your for your answer, and I would like to ask how to check the browser version is IE or not? And the error is from the xml.open, am I just replace the code you suggested? Thank you.